# Open source and free Windows SSH server

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, ssh

I'm looking for an open source and free Windows SSH server.

Comment: [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) is the closest I know. It's free, bu for getting the source you have to buy another program from them (which disqualifies it as "open source"), and it's also unmaintained since 2009.

Comment: Another option could be using a Linux software (there are a few of them) under some sort of emulation (virtual machine, Cygwin or, on Windows 10, the native Bash command prompt).

Comment: I'll probably just run a linux setup either under Win10 or an actual vm.

Comment: bitvise used to have a free ssh server ' Personal Edition' for individual noncommercial use but it is not open source. It works great for administering a Windows Server instance which serves as a development machine for a sole developer, for example. Read this carefully: https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-pricing

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is working on official OpenSSH port - [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/). It is not done yet, but it worked for me pretty well.